# Calling fragment method from activity Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I know this issue was discussed many times, but no solution works for me. I have an `activity` with `fragment` attached and using `interface` I'm calling a method from my `activity` that is replacing this `fragment` with another one. I want this method also to call a method from my new 'fragment', but however I implement that the application crashes when reaching this point. Does somebody know a solution for that? I'm new to Android development.

```
public void replacingMethod(String text){

    NewFragment newFragment = new NewFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    NewFragment f = (NewFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.new_fragment);
    f.displayText(text);
}
```

I've tried to call `displayText()` from `newFragment` before and after replacement but it didn't work.

Comment: add your logcat stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fragment should be attached to the activity to display text. The right way is to pass the text you want to show to the fragment using it's arguments with `Fragment#setArguments(Bundle)` and then get it inside fragment using `Fragment#getArguments()`.

Comment: That woks perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the fragment using the `R.id.fragment_container` instead of `R.id.new_fragment`.

Comment: This will work later on. Once the fragment was attached (lets say, after an asynctask, or whatever). As @Potapov said, when you create the fragment the best way is using `Fragment#setArguments`.